# How to convert an array of indexed objects to a plain object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

How to convert an array of this type:

```
place:
[
     {
         "_id": "xxxxx",
         "loc": [
             0: "xxx",
             1: "xxx"
         ]
     }
]
```

To something like this:

```
place:
{
  lat: "xxx"
  lng: "xxx"
  _id: "xxxxx"
}
```

Using javascript, I tried something like

```
let object = {};

place.forEach(element => {
     object[element[0]] = element[1];
});
```

but it did not work for me, I am using angular to make a method and I need to convert the array of objects that I am showing

Comment: the first issue is that the input is not a valid javascript construct ... i.e. `["0":"xxx"` won't parse - so, not sure how you managed to run anything against that input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the totally invalid

```
"loc": [
    0: "xxx",
    1: "xxx"
]
```

is actually just

```
"loc": [
    "xxx",
    "xxx"
]
```

```js
let place =
[
     {
         "_id": "xxxxx",
         "loc": [
             "xxx",
             "xxx"
         ]
     }
]

let { _id, loc: [lat, lng]} = place[0];
let output = { _id, lat, lng};
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Actually about the invalid is just an example, I wanted to imply the structure of the array, but thank you very much for explaining. I really needed it

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have another question, this is efficient if I have N amount of array of objects, I mean if instead of just one I have up to five in it